# How get telegram user info by UserID?

Tags: python-telegram-bot, tdlib

I have a `user_id` like 2024211111. How i can get user info by this user_id?
Tdlib api have a method called `getUser`, but it doesn't work with this user_id (**this user_id not in my ChatList**)

Comment: are you asking about tdlib or about the Bot API? `python-telegram-bot` is a wrapper for the bot API, not for MTProto

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: **This function doesn't exist**. You just can know User Info through a chat previously initiated. So, you have to start a chat with this user first to call the API method mentioned. If you need to query the info later, you should store it, there is no another way that I know